# How to make a Toast when users Scrolls beyond on first and last items in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to implement  View Pager and succeed in it.
 Currently I am using a Listener to load some contents from DB when a page is selected But I don't know How to make a toast when users try to scroll beyond the first and the last items in the ViewPager.  
This is my Listner

```
.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {    


            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

                getMonthdays(arg0);
                Global.setSelectedMonth(""+(currentpos+1));

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                System.out.println(" onPageScrollStateChanged : "+arg0);

            }
        });
```

I think onPageScrollStateChanged can be used But i dont know how to do it... 
Please Help me, Any Ideas and Suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Check index of item in the following method

```
    @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }
```

then if the index is last then show the Toast. Easy :)

For detecting the Gesture of the user override this method and do some maths.

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

or you can refer the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307560/onfling-set-gesturedetector-to-all-child-views)

Comment: But i think there is a problem if the user tries to scroll backwards from the last item How to detect that and the same case  for the first one tooo.