# Swiping between XML layouts with OnGestureListener or OnGesturePerformedListener

Tags: android, android-layout, swipe, gesture-recognition

I am trying to implement swiping between pages on my Application. I currently have 5 XML layout files which I access all from one Activity. There are five buttons on the bottom which represent each layout and when pressed switch to the corresponding XML layout.

I have tried to implement swiping using `OnGestureListener`, but it does not work as I would like it to. I need to swipe the `Title` of the view for the swiping to work. It does not work when I swipe across any of the Views shown in the layout.

I began looking and found the `GestureOverlayView`, which seems to be what I want. However, all of implementations I've found give me problems. [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html), [Similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434258/using-a-gesture-overlay-view-in-android).

This is the code that I have so far:

```
public class Monitor extends Activity implements android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, OnGesturePerformedListener {
    private GestureDetector gestureScanner;
    private GestureOverlayView gestures;
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 50;
    private GestureLibrary gestureLib;

    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        gestures = new GestureOverlayView(this);
        View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        gestures.addView(inflate);
        gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
        gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures); // Error here
        if (!gestureLib.load()) {
           finish();
         }
        setContentView(gestures);
}
```

I get an error on the line `gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource();`. The error is `raw cannot be resolved or is not a field.`. There is no `raw` folder in my `/project-name/res/` directory. Any ideas? Is there another way to do this?

This is how I first implemented the swiping capability, which only worked across the title bar.

```
public class Monitor extends Activity implements android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    private GestureDetector gestureScanner;
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 50;
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);
        setContentView( R.layout.monitor );
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i( "TouchEvent", "Here" );
        return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
        if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY
            ) {
            Log.i( "OnFling", "Right" );
            //ur code goes here.            
            if( getTitle().equals( getString( R.string.main_analogs ) ) ) {
                setContentView( R.layout.monitor );
                setTitle( R.string.main_monitor );
                buildButtons();
                if( hasRead ) {
                    updateMonitorForm();
                }
            }
        }
        /* on scroll to the previous page  */
        else if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY
            ) {
            Log.i( "OnFling", "Left" );
            //Ur code goes here
            if( getTitle().equals( getString( R.string.main_monitor ) ) ) {
                setContentView( R.layout.analogs );
                setTitle( R.string.main_analogs );
            buildButtons();
                if( hasRead ) {
                    updateMonitorForm();
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: A `ViewPager` doesn't help?

Comment: A ViewPager will most likely help but I haven't found any good examples. I have looked through the provided docs but I still do not completely understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to implement swiping between pages on my Application. I
>   currently have 5 XML layout files which I access all from one
>   Activity. There are five buttons on the bottom which represent each
>   layout and when pressed switch to the corresponding XML layout.

This will be an ideal scenario for the `ViewPager` widget(unless you forgot to add other important details). You can manually swipe the `ViewPager`(so you don't need to handle the touch events on your own) and you could also set the current page of the `ViewPager` with the `setCurrentItem` method(the `Buttons` part).

I've made my little example based on your scenario. The sample it's pretty self explanatory and you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/4476966).

Comment: Thanks, I don't have time to look over it just yet but this looks like exactly what I needed to see. Question on the XML layout though. The one in the example with all of the buttons. The way I am currently set up is five separate XML layouts that are currently. switched using `setContentView()` in button listeners. If I want a blank slate to just throw these five layouts in, would my XML simply have the one `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` element? Within a `LinearLayout` or something?

Comment: @JuiCe The `ViewPager` will act as the `Activity` container. So yes,  you'll set the content view for the `Activity` to a layout file which will contain only the `ViewPager`(wrapped in another layout if you wish).

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks. What's the purpose of having the five buttons in that XML file then? Are they like a tab bar on the bottom of the ViewPager area?

Comment: @JuiCe Well in your question you said something about having 5 buttons at the bottom that are used for switching the layouts...

Comment: True, sorry didn't realize I had mentioned that to you. Thanks

Comment: One more question if you see this. I am working in SDK version 10, will. I am currently writing out the new XML files and have `The following classes could not be found: -android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` pop up

Comment: @JuiCe The `ViewPager` isn't available in the SDK(any version included), it's part of the compatibility package(as you can see the declaration in the layout file). If you import the compatibility jar in your project you'll find the `ViewPager`.

Comment: I am now trying to implement a solution using the sample you gave me, but Eclipse does not recognize a `SwipeAdapter` nor can I find it online anywhere. Did you mean something else, or do I need to install more support?

Comment: @JuiCe Please read more carefully my sample code(in the link in my answer). The `SwipeAdapter`(just a name) is an extension of `PagerAdapter` made by me.

Comment: Just popping by to thank you for the example. Worked marvelously for my purpose!