# Detecting left and right swipe android?

Tags: android

I have a RelativeLayout defined as follows:

```
<RelativeLayot>

  <TextView />
  <TextView />
  <EditText />
  <Button />

</RelativeLayout
```

I want to detect swipes to the left or right on this RelativeLayout and update the two textviews with new text. What is the easiest or most efficient way of goiing about doing this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To detect swipes either left or right we use Gesture in android. Please go through following link shows you different kinds gesture you can capture.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Gesture overlay for detecting the swipes.You can create left and right swipes through gesture builder . Refer to this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html or this [Using a gesture overlay view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434258/using-a-gesture-overlay-view-in-android) . Developer docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html

Comment: Im confused DO I need to define the gestures? I just need to simple detect left or right?

Comment: follow the first link. First you need to create left and right gesture through gesture builder . then you can detect left and right swipes by implementing gesture overlay over your layout