# OnTouchListener on entire Activity

Tags: android, swipe, gesture, touch-event

I'm trying to detect a **onFling** event on the entire area of my *activity*. To do this I:

1) set the *GestureDetectorCompat*:

```
private GestureDetectorCompat gDetect;
```

2) in *OnCreate* initialize the detector:

```
gDetect = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureListener());
```

3) override the *onTouchEvent*:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gDetect.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

4) create the *GestureListener* class:

```
class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.e(null, "onFling: " + event1.toString() + event2.toString());
        return super.onFling(event1, event2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }

}
```

It works, but it detects *onFling* gesture **ONLY** in the part of my UI where there is not any other view. So, if I swipe in a blank area it works, if I swipe in a part of the *activity* where is another view (for example a *ScrollView* or a *LinearLayout*) the detection isn't triggered.

I hope I've explained my problem: **how I can detect gesture on the entire surface** of the Activity, to accomplish a simple swipe gesture?

Many tanks.

Comment: Have you thought of making the entire layout of your activity clickable?

Comment: No, can U suggest the code please? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this, try passing to parent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374592/passing-touch-events-to-the-parent-view

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GestureOverlayView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html). Here is a great starter resource for [GestureOverlayView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGestures/article.html) . Also you can have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434258/using-a-gesture-overlay-view-in-android).

Basically to use this your application must use the view "GestureOverlayView" and you place your other views in this view. Your activity must implement the interface "OnGesturePerformedListener" and if a gesture is detected then "onGesturePerformedListener" method is called.

Hope this helps. Goodluck!