# How to use gesture on specific place of screen in android

Tags: android, android-gesture

I am wondering how to check if the user is performing gesture on our predefined area. I have an criteria and that is , let suppose , If I have a transparent graphics of word "B" on the screen , then user should start filling it with color with gesture (with the touch of his finger). he starts it with the below corner of the B and end up how we write the b when writing with the pencil.

So how to achieve this type of gesture and how to just restrict user to use the gesture on on that part of the screen ? please any idea about it or share me any thing which is similar to it.

Comment: Have you tried using [GestureOverLayView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5434258/1841194)?

Comment: nopes ? would it work

Comment: I've not tested your requirements on it. However it seems to meet your requirements.

Comment: it is just about gestures left and right and doing on it any thing you want , but I want a specific pattern to be drawn , For example the oval , the when the user should stat finger drawing , then it should not draw anything out side it